# MemoryError at ... No exception message supplied

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a very simple ManyToMany relationship:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Mot(BaseModel):
    groupes_categories = models.ManyToManyField(GroupeCategories, blank=True,
                                                through='MotGroupeCategories',
                                                symmetrical=False,
                                                related_name='mot')
    texte = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return _(u'{}').format(self.texte)


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class GroupeCategories(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    exemple = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, default=None,
                               null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return _(u'{0}{1}').format(
            self.description,
            u' ({0})'.format(self.exemple) if self.exemple else u''
        )


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class MotGroupeCategories(models.Model):
    mot = models.ForeignKey(Mot, blank=False)
    groupe_categories = models.ForeignKey(GroupeCategories, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'{} - {}'.format(self.mot.texte,
                                 self.groupe_categories.description)
```

I've done this many times, and everything works fine except when I want to edit via administration a `MotGroupeCategories`:

```
class MotGroupeCategoriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def mot_texte(self, obj):
        return obj.mot.texte
    mot_texte.allow_tags = True
    mot_texte.short_description = _(u'I.')

    fields = ('mot', 'groupe_categories')
    list_display = ('groupe_categories', 'mot_texte', 'id')
    list_display_links = list_display
    search_fields = ['description']


admin.site.register(MotGroupeCategories, MotGroupeCategoriesAdmin)
```

Everything works fine except when I want to edit a `MotGroupeCategories`: all those admins urls like:

```
/admin/main/motgroupecategories/[id]/
```

result in

```
MemoryError at /admin/main/motgroupecategories/12060915/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: GET
Request URL:        /admin/main/motgroupecategories/[id]/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: MemoryError
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py
    in render_options, line 547
```

It's the first time I have such a strange problem and nothing like that on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have tried your code. Seems no problem with light data.
You may need to trace the error on rendering options for widgets.

`Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py
    in render_options, line 547`

And what if you remove __str__ method from both `Mot` and `GroupeCategories` for a testing.

Comment: I know why. My foreign table has **`2 446 963`** rows. So it Django tries to fill a `<select>` with **`2 446 963`** values. Here's the explanation of my question. Now I'm just wondering whether I answer here and ask another question or just modify it.

Comment: Well it's worse than that: it's a manytomany so this implies that for *each manytomany*, in a Inline admin, there's a combo of 2446963 values...

Comment: Have you tried removing __str__ methods?

Comment: What about using `raw_id_field` for your `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: @kia Yes I replaced all  str by "return 'x'" so the problem doesnt come from here.

Comment: You know, I have inserted about `2M` records in `Mot` randomly.
I had to kill my chrome and python process afer not getting any response from loading the page, which was also your page of problem too.
I think it's really heavy to be load as `2M` options for `select` element.
If I were you, I would use custom widget featured lazy loading or django `row_id_field` widget.

Comment: @kia Thank you for your suggestion, may I ask you to answer below with, maybe, one or two links pointing to some stuff like you suggest? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `raw_id_fields` please refer to [Django's Admin raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)

For writing your custom lazy loading `ModelChoiceField` please refer to [Django Custom Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not the answer to the question but it can help to clarify the type of situation that can give this error, at least it would have helped me.

I got MemoryError when using django rest framework becuase I had a foreign key to a table with 2000000+ items in it and the web browsable API wanted to add all the items to the drop down.